# React native fetch api

Tags: reactjs, frontend, fetch

```
  logOut = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@session_token');
    return fetch('http:10.0.2.2:3333/api/1.0.0/logout',{
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'X-Authorization': value,
      },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('User logged out: ', value)
        } else if (response.status === 401) {
          ToastAndroid.show('your not logged in', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        } else {
          throw 'something went wrong';
        }
      });
    }
```

I am trying to perform a logout function to the API i have set up however i am receiving a unhandled promise rejection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your API call requires an authorization token then you need to pass that into your fetch call. Try something like this, may need to be adjusted based on what type of authorization is on your api.

```
const token = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/1.0.0/find', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `token ${token}`
  }
})
```

Comment: const token = AsyncStorage.getItem('session_token');

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    //send fetch to url
      fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/1.0.0/find', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `token ${token}`,
        },
      }
    //convert the response to json
      .then((response) => response.json())
    //set the json response equal to the data objects 'shopData'
      .then((responseJson) => {
          setLoading(false);
          setShopData(responseJson);
      })
    //catch any errors
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      }));
  });

Comment: ive tried this but it is still returning the same error?

Comment: I don't know what your api uses for authorization so I have no way of knowing how to help. You'll need to dig into your API and see what kind of authentication it is using and if it is receiving the token correctly.